# Coredata: Setting the Related Object Takes Too Long

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, core-data

CoreData Entity Structure:

`Invoice <---->> Invoiceline <<-----> Product`

NSManaged object class implementation

```
// intended to be overridden by the subclass 
class var entityName { /* return the entity name */ }

// generic class function to create new entity
class func create() -> NSManagedObject
{
  let context = // the main context
  let record = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(self.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
  return record
}
```

Sample transaction:

```
let product = // a product object
let invoice = Invoice.create() as! Invoice
let invoiceLine = InvoiceLine.create() as! InvoiceLine

invoiceLine.product = product
invoiceLine.invoice = invoice

// complete the transaction
invoice.checktout()
```

When the the number of invoices being inserted in the coredata reaches 200K, setting `invoiceLine's` `product` property takes too long:

```
invoiceLine.product = product
```

So, I use XCode instrument to check for memory allocations, I found out that, everytime I `invoiceLine.product = product`, coredata is loading all the related `invoiceLines` for `product`, in my case 6K of `invoiceLines`, so when I relate another `product` to `invoiceLine` it will, again, load all related `invoiceLine` for that particular `product`, eventually the memory allocation gets larger and larger.

**Question:** Is it possible to prevent coredata from loading all related `invoiceLine` for `product` when I do: `invoiceLine.product = product`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a good practice, but I manage to reduce the execution time by cutting off the inverse relation of the `product` to `invoiceline`:

`invoiceLine ----> product`

This time, CoreData has no reason to load all related `invoiceline` for the particular `product` which I don't need, thus, enhancing the performance.